# Oracle wallet on autonomus database

Tags: oracle

how to create wallet in Oracle autonomus database. On premise we have database server but on cloud we dont see server files. Maybe to create in on another server and upload it to storage?

Comment: You cannot create server-side wallets or configuration files with Autonomous Database. You can download pre-configured wallets from the service console for use with clients like SQL Developer.

Comment: @pmdba i dont mean on database configuration wallet. I m talking about wallet for storing ssl certificate for https requests FROM database not to cennect to database. I can make one one premise using orapki utility but how to do this on cloud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot upload custom wallets to Oracle Autonomous Database. You must use their pre-configured wallet with commonly used SSL root certificates. You cannot connect to sites with self-signed certificates using UTL_HTTP.

From the documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/appendix-database-pl-sql-packages-restrictions.html#GUID-829A7D07-1EA4-4F59-AA60-F780FABAFDEC):

> **PL/SQL Packages Restrictions**
>
> **UTL_HTTP Restrictions**
>
> - Connections through IP addresses are not allowed.
> - Only HTTPS connections are allowed (HTTP and HTTP_PROXY are disallowed).
> - All web services must be secured. The only allowed ports are 443 and 8443. Your instance is preconfigured with an Oracle Wallet that
>   contains more than 90 of the most commonly trusted root and
>   intermediate SSL certificates. This Oracle Wallet is centrally managed
>   and therefore you cannot consume 3rd party web services that are
>   protected using self-signed SSL certificates.
> - The SET_AUTHENTICATION_FROM_WALLET procedure is disallowed.
> - The WALLET_PATH and WALLET_PASSWORD arguments for the CREATE_REQUEST_CONTEXT, REQUEST, and REQUEST_PIECES APIs are ignored.
> - Oracle Wallet configuration cannot be altered. All arguments for SET_WALLET API are ignored.
> - UTL_HTTP usage is audited by default. You cannot disable auditing for UTL_HTTP.
> - The UTL_HTTP URL must be accessible over the internet. The UTL_HTTP call is unable to reach URLs that are on private subnets or behind
>   on-premises firewalls.

And see here:

- https://enesi.no/2021/03/utl_http-from-oracle-autonomous-database/

Comment: thank you for answer, i read this in documentation and it is written in PACKAGE itself (comented in utl HTTP PACKAGE) but i didnt understand it well, i thought that self signed certificate are forbidden but its posible to create wallet with exported trusted certificate. I have report server signed with letsencrypt certificate SO maybe thers Chance it Will work. And its hosted on Oracle vm instance. It would be logical that autonomus db and vm Oracle instance can comunicate on some private subnet but its imposible

Comment: thank you for help. I Conected using pre configured wallet on web server with letsencrypt ssl certificate. I didnt Know that before util http request i have to execute wallet comand without parameter. Never seen that in documentation